# Add item to Azure Service Bus queue when a specific database table record is inserted/updated/deleted

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, triggers

I have a website written in MVC.NET and running in Azure App Services with an Azure SQL database, Entity Framework code first.

What I'm trying to achieve is to add an item to an Azure Service Bus queue when I insert, update or delete a record in a specific SQL table.

Assume I have three tables T1, T2 and T3. I want to add a queue item when I insert, update or delete in table T1 and T2 but not T3.

I have been looking at either using [Entity Framework Triggers](https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers) but I don't know if it's possible to specify the individual tables the trigger should be applied to or only across the entire database.

Another option is SQL Triggers. Then I can target the tables I like but it's hard to debug and the code is separated from the rest of my codebase.

What is the best way to achieve this and are there any other ways than the two described above?

Comment: Could you enqueue the intent as a single message and delegate that to another process to take care of it?

Comment: @SeanFeldman I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: What I meant is not performing queuing work in the triggers.

Comment: @SeanFeldman So are you suggesting instead of writing to the queue from a trigger, write to the queue in the code where applicable? If so why is this better?

Comment: Something among the lines. Having your ASB processing logic in SQL sounds very off.

Comment: How did you end up implementing this?